# Accessing derived class from base class pointer with a fixed array size

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, derived-class, base-class

I'm trying to write a function parkVehicle(), this function has to access the read member function of the derived class through a Base class pointer. How can I access it?

```
class Parking {
     const int MAX_SPOTS_NO = 100;
    Base B[MAX_SPOTS_NO];
    void parkVehicle() const;

}


class Base : public Read {
    std::istream& read(std::istream& istr = std::cin);
}

class derived : public Base {
    std::istream& read(std::istream& istr = std::cin);
}


class Read{
virtual std::istream& read(std::istream& istr = std::cin) = 0; 
}



void parkVehicle() {
    //call read from the derived class
}
```

Comment: There are at least two fundamental C++ reasons why you can't. C++ objects simply don't work this way. You need to implement virtual inheritance, and you need to do something about object slicing. C++ is not Java. For more information, see your C++ textbook.

Comment: If you think you need to access a derived class member through a base class pointer, your design is very likely flawed. Back up a few steps and rethink your approach. (Possibly, you want a virtual function in your base class, but do review your approach to make sure the abstraction levels make sense.)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, your class design needs to be revised. However, just for the shake of answering to your queries, you can modify like so - variable  MAX_SPOTS_NO needs to be declared as static and the member variable B may be declared as pointer array ( prefer to use smart pointers instead) to avoid cyclic redundancy issue

```
class Base; // forward declaration

class Parking {
public:
    static const int MAX_SPOTS_NO = 100;
    Base* B[MAX_SPOTS_NO];
    void parkVehicle() ;

};

void Parking::parkVehicle() {
    //call read from the derived class
    B[0] = new Base();
    B[0]->read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is [slicing the objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/), so there are no `derived` objects in the array, only `Base` objects.  Polymorphism works only when accessing objects via a pointer or a reference, so you need to change your array to hold `Base*` pointers:

```cpp
class Parking {
    static const int MAX_SPOTS_NO = 100;
    Base* B[MAX_SPOTS_NO];
    void parkVehicle() const;
};

void parkVehicle() {
    //call read from the derived class
    ...
    B[index]->read();
    ...
}
```

Then you can store `derived` objects in the array as needed, eg <sup>1</sup>:

```cpp
derived *d = new derived;
B[index] = d;
```

Or:

```cpp
derived d;
B[index] = &d;
```

<sup>1: You did not provide enough of your code to show you exactly HOW you should best create, manage, and store your `derived` objects.</sup>